# distribute third party application on azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to know if there is a process that deploys/distribute third party applications on azure virtual machines. I have these windows applications that will be deployed on newly provisioned virtual machines. May I know if there is a automated process on this one? currently we have our custom template and we want to use images from the marketplace and deploy these applications automatically.

thanks!

Comment: I would use Powershell for that. See also [this](http://kunaludapi.blogspot.nl/2015/09/multiple-ways-to-install-software.html) article.

Comment: Thank you Joreon. This helps on my research.